# android detecting touch

Tags: android

I have a webview, and a touch listener on the viewContainer. What I want is, when a touch is detected lights out mode is on, and also if that touch is on a clickable area over webview that click must do his work.

Now touchlistener just not working over my webview.

Here is my similar question, which is not answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433718/view-lights-out-mode

I will be really appreciate your answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [onInterseptTouchEvent(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29), where you can track touch events on their way to childviews and consume them in the parentview. Thus, you might consume first touch if lights are out. Good luck :)